# Firebase Dynamic Links - custom domain with custom logo/favicon

Tags: firebase-hosting, skype, firebase-dynamic-links

I have set up dynamic links with a custom domain name, now my dynamic links look something like this:
`https://my.domain.com/xXxX`

But, when I share these links via Skype, there's a Firebase logo in the **bottom left corner**.

[image: sharing via Skype - Firebase logo instead of custom logo]

**I would like to change this logo to my custom logo. How can I achieve that?**

**Edit:** I've tried adding a `favicon.ico` file to the hosting, but it didn't help.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: No, not yet. I've experimented with uploading custom favicons in different formats to my custom domain hosted on Firebase but with no success. The good news is that the logo is **only** visible in Skype, so it's not really a problem for other messaging apps

Comment: When I share it to someone on whatsapp, I still get the same issue @EricGopak . Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Thanks for the update, and no I haven't tried since back then. If you find a way to make it work, let us know :)